# Video Popup using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-iframe-api

Please am making use of iframe and I want the video to popup when ever someone hits play, but I don't want to add a custom play button. How can I go about this? I've checked some online courses and even here on stackoverflow, but I didn't really get what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

In tags of your question I see `youtube-iframe-api` and I guess that you are using this API.

This utility only creates iframe with, as far as I know, without even option to play immediately after load.
Website inside Iframe element can't be controlled in any ways- it is security issue, becouse then you will be albe to do whatever you want on any page you choose after somebody comes to your website.
So the answer is:

No, it is impossible until this API doesn't allow you to do that.